# Is this a valid way to show an infinite sheet of charge has a uniform field using Gauss's law?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

[image]

From a pre-academic studies book, the example uses a gaussian surface *outside* of the charged sheet to show that because the flux through it is 0, the field on both ends has to be equal. Is this a valid use of Gauss's law?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. The Gauss law
$$\int_S \vec E.d\vec S={Q_{\rm int}\over\varepsilon_0}$$
applies to all closed surface $S$.